# Optimization of resources in Excel

Tags: excel, optimization, resources

I'm struggling with a task of optimization of resources, and I wonder if someone knows any efficient way to find the optimal solution for it, using only Excel. I explain what I'm trying to achieve:

Suppose you are managing an assembly factory for metal tubes. Your raw material is standard size tubes, and then in your factory you need to cut these tubes according to a list of requests from clients, with very specific sizes. All tubes are of the same type, so we can reuse leftovers from each cut, if the length of that leftover is sufficient to satisfy any tube request.
We can also group small length requests to be made from one single tube, for example, on the attached list, we could use one 8 metre tube to deliver the last four entries (1,615+1,62+1,625+1,67), with 1,47 leftover wasted.

Assuming a long list of requests, and that the tubes supplied are **8 metres each**, do you know of any way of calculating how many tubes I have to order to satisfy the list of requests, minimising the losses per each cut?

[Example of request list, each entry is in metres](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ha9zT.png)

Comment: this is known as a "cutting stock" problem and is very common in linear programming.  You *might* be able to tackle it in excel.  try google searching it with that term.  wikipedia has thorough explanation of the approach

Comment: Thanks. I searched and studied the "cutting stock problem", and that's exactly what I need. However I'm still strugging to have it working, since all the examples I find are for a small number of different cuts (in many examples this is about 3 different sizes, while I have around 246 different sizes I need to cut).
I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=922BuM87LYw
But since I have so many different sizes, the number of possible combinations is huge(?) Do you know how can I have that sorted? Through VBA perhaps?

Comment: So, I think it depends on how important it is to get to a good answer here.  I'm not sure how I would do this in Excel, and I am not a fan of VBA.  The solver in Excel is a POS compared to what is freely available in other domains.  Try looking for an example in Excel or there are several excel gurus here who might chime in.  Realize with more sizes, depending on quantities, etc., it becomes easier to make good approximations and waste less.  If you really wanna dig in, consider transitioning to `python` and a free solver.

Comment: Larger numbers can be handled using a technique called Column Generation. See Lasdon, Optimization Theory for Large Systems. for an example.